# How do I get HTTP Headers [Links Only] using a Web Browser in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to an Add-on called Live Http Headers used with Firefox. I'm not trying to get the Headers or cookies, but the links that load on the page itself. Let us assume I visited Mail.Yahoo.com, this is pretty much what you would see when I use the add-on.

[CLICK HERE](http://i51.tinypic.com/2iiuxyd.jpg)

How can I achieve something similar ? Only the links that load on the page itself ! 
I'm looking forward into reading your suggestions, please enlighten me if you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the webpage using a webclient instance
Then with the result string, you can get the urls using a regular expression
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm